# get records of a table doesnt exists in another table + sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two tables as below:

Table A:

```
AIID  AID  AName
1     200   'A'
2     200   'B'
3     200   'C'
4     300   'D'
5     300   'E'
6     400   'F'
7     400   'G'

Table B:

BID  AIID   AID   AName
 1     2     200    'B'
 2     6     400    'F'
```

Now I need to get the records from Table A, all AIIDs by AID wise, whose AIID is greater than AIID's in table B by AID wise, also any new AID records.

Ex, I need to get the below rows from Table A:

```
AIID  AID  AName
3     200   'C'
4     300   'D'
5     300   'E'
7     400   'G'
```

Can some body advise how to write query for this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your problem, this should do it;

```
SELECT TableA.*
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB
  ON TableA.AID  = TableB.AID
 AND TableA.AIID <= TableB.AIID
WHERE TableB.BID IS NULL;
```

It basically does the reverse, it finds all entries in A that have a larger or equal entry in B and eliminates them. The rest are returned.

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/71c2f/7).

Comment: `WHERE TableB.BID IS NULL` what does this signify ?

Comment: @Dusht In combination with a `LEFT JOIN`, it means that there's no row in TableB that matches the `ON` clause. In other words, there is no line in TableB that has the same `AID` and a greater or equal `AIID`.